# EXTJS directory structure: What can be deleted?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've downloaded the latest version of ExtJS (4.0.7) and am deploying it on my local webserver (localhost). This is the default directory structure of ExtJS 4.0.7 (see screenshot). I want this to be absolutely minimal.

1. So which are the directories and files I can delete? I don't need
   documentation, extra themes, build scripts etc. Just need the bare
   minimum to have EXT and its widgets working.
2. Which top level .js files can I delete? If I keep ext-all.js, can I
   delete the other js files in the same level? (i.e. can I delete
   other files like ext-debug.js, ext-all-debug.js etc?)

[image: ExtJS 4.0.7 Directory Structure]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want it to be (data) minimal, use ext.js and follow Sencha's deployment tools guide to build a single file with only the components you need.

If you want to minimize the number of files, keep ext-all.js (and probably ext-all-dev for development too) and the resources folder. You can trim down the resources folder too if you really want to. For example, you don't need the images for every theme.